# Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download... in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

When I try to build android app I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processTESTDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:TESTDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8.
         > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8.
         > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8/x86_debug-1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8/x86_debug-1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8.
         > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-40a99c595137e4b2f5b2efa8ff343ea23c1e16b8.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 30s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
```

I'm using Mac OS, flutter and android studio. I can build iOS app without any such error.How can I fix this?

I tried this one,

```
Go to flutter_app => android => gradle => wrapper directory
Delete gradle-wrapper.jar file
Open and edit gradle-wrapper.properties file
Change distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x.x.x-all.zip to gradle-7.2-all.zip or latest
On terminal use flutter run command
```

But still I get the same error.

this is my android/build.gradle file:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

As it says in stack trace, try to download dependencies from url `https://google.bintray.com/` but get `502 http error`. if you test this link on browser you'll get this error too. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70198024/5005756) this might be temporary error from the repository.

you can also replace all your `jcenter()` from your `repository` closure in `build.gradle` with `mavenCentral()`. sync Gradle and build again.

Comment: It already has mavenCentral()

Comment: @Shashiwadana Could you post both your build.gradle? (I mean both root and app module .gradle). As I know if you had set all your repository to maven central it wouldn't  try to download from this link.

Comment: I added root build.gradle file

Comment: @Shashiwadana you have 
`all projects{
....
maven {url 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer'}
}`
And you may try to resolve one of exoplayer dependencies  which is not in mavenCentral so Gradle pass this repository to google bintray and `google.binray.com` is temporary down. check this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69318147/could-not-find-com-google-android-exoplayerexoplayer-corer2-4-2) and try to find suitable version of exoplayer in `mavenCentral` or wait till problem in google bintray being solved.